# Recovery from Scalpel didn't show any recovered file

Tags: 14.04, command-line, data-recovery, su, undelete

I have deleted some of my .odt files by mistake last night (near about 10 hours ago), and I had to recover those files as those were really important to me. I used scalepel for this purpose in which I gave command:

```
scalpel /dev/sda2 -b -o ~/Desktop/fhghghg
```

I had my files that were deleted in sda2 and I don't have any other partition except that. So I made a folder on Desktop. It took 2 hours to complete the process:

```
    Scalpel version 1.60
Written by Golden G. Richard III, based on Foremost 0.69.

Opening target "/dev/sda2"

Image file pass 1/2.
/dev/sda2:  33.2% |************                         |  154.0 GB  1:27:29 ETA

/dev/sda2: 100.0% |*************************************|  463.5 GB    00:00 ETA
Carve lists built.  Workload:
odt with header "\x50\x4b\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x6d\x69\x6d\x65\x74\x79\x70\x65\x61\x70\x70\x6c\x69\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x2f\x76\x6e\x64\x2e\x6f\x61\x73\x69\x73\x2e\x6f\x70\x65\x6e\x64\x6f\x63\x75\x6d\x65\x6e\x74\x2e\x74\x65\x78\x74\x50\x4b" and footer "\x4d\x45\x54\x41\x2d\x49\x4e\x46\x2f\x6d\x61\x6e\x69\x66\x65\x73\x74\x2e\x78\x6d\x6c\x50\x4b\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f" --> 193 files
ods with header "\x50\x4b\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x6d\x69\x6d\x65\x74\x79\x70\x65\x61\x70\x70\x6c\x69\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x2f\x76\x6e\x64\x2e\x6f\x61\x73\x69\x73\x2e\x6f\x70\x65\x6e\x64\x6f\x63\x75\x6d\x65\x6e\x74\x2e\x73\x70\x72\x65\x61\x64\x73\x68\x65\x65\x74\x50\x4b" and footer "\x4d\x45\x54\x41\x2d\x49\x4e\x46\x2f\x6d\x61\x6e\x69\x66\x65\x73\x74\x2e\x78\x6d\x6c\x50\x4b\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f" --> 14 files
odp with header "\x50\x4b\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x6d\x69\x6d\x65\x74\x79\x70\x65\x61\x70\x70\x6c\x69\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x2f\x76\x6e\x64\x2e\x6f\x61\x73\x69\x73\x2e\x6f\x70\x65\x6e\x64\x6f\x63\x75\x6d\x65\x6e\x74\x2e\x70\x72\x65\x73\x65\x6e\x74\x61\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x50\x4b" and footer "\x4d\x45\x54\x41\x2d\x49\x4e\x46\x2f\x6d\x61\x6e\x69\x66\x65\x73\x74\x2e\x78\x6d\x6c\x50\x4b\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f\x3f" --> 26 files
Carving files from image.
Image file pass 2/2.
/dev/sda2: 100.0% |*************************************|  463.5 GB    00:00 ETAProcessing of image file complete. Cleaning up...
Done.
Scalpel is done, files carved = 233, elapsed = 7178 seconds.
```

And in desktop folder I got the folder having lock icon(as I had run all the commands in root mode) and it has just one file **audit.text**.I didn't get any of my odt file and folder has lock icon too.

The thing is that, on "ls -l fhghghg/" it is showing:

```
    total 28
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12713 Jul  4 12:59 audit.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jul  4 12:58 odp-2-0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jul  4 12:58 ods-1-0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jul  4 12:59 odt-0-0
```

And on " cat fhghghg/audit.txt ", it is showing:

```
Scalpel version 1.60 audit file
Started at Mon Jul  4 10:59:22 2016
Command line:
scalpel /dev/sda2 -b -o /root/Desktop/fhghghg 

Output directory: /root/Desktop/fhghghg
Configuration file: /etc/scalpel/scalpel.conf

Opening target "/dev/sda2"

The following files were carved:
File          Start         Chop        Length      Extracted From
00000000.odt    165150720       NO            66578     sda2
00000001.odt   1549533184       NO           175449     sda2
00000002.odt   1558052864       NO            72438     sda2
00000003.odt  33336066048       NO            66656     sda2
00000004.odt  35885285376       NO            67311     sda2
00000005.odt 112145858560       NO            74935     sda2
00000006.odt 174892515328       NO           356733     sda2
00000207.odp 223076155392       NO          1603418     sda2
00000208.odp 223283773440       NO          1603418     sda2
00000211.odp 245120432145       NO              131     sda2
00000210.odp 245120381927       NO              131     sda2
00000209.odp 245120365543       NO              131     sda2
00000195.ods 245120432301       NO              131     sda2
00000194.ods 245120381771       NO              131     sda2
00000193.ods 245120365387       NO              131     sda2
00000009.odt 245120432457       NO              123     sda2
00000008.odt 245120381623       NO              123     sda2
00000007.odt 245120365239       NO              123     sda2
00000010.odt 245957844992       NO            57678     sda2
00000013.odt 245990367232       NO            51457     sda2
00000012.odt 245989691392       NO            50606     sda2
00000011.odt 245989638144       NO            50606     sda2
00000015.odt 246002446336       NO            57673     sda2
00000014.odt 245998026752       NO            57673     sda2
00000022.odt 246127157248       NO            61235     sda2
00000021.odt 246126817280       NO            60494     sda2
00000020.odt 246126682112       NO            59831     sda2
00000019.odt 246126301184       NO            59549     sda2
00000018.odt 246126145536       NO            59230     sda2
00000017.odt 246126084096       NO            59230     sda2
00000016.odt 246125953024       NO            58893     sda2
00000029.odt 246242107392       NO            60355     sda2
00000028.odt 246242045952       NO            60355     sda2
00000027.odt 246241820672       NO            60568     sda2
00000026.odt 246241746944       NO            60568     sda2
00000025.odt 246241685504       NO            60568     sda2
00000024.odt 246241480704       NO            59879     sda2
00000023.odt 246241296384       NO            56023     sda2
00000031.odt 246270717952       NO            60781     sda2
00000030.odt 246270656512       NO            60781     sda2
00000032.odt 246350348288       NO            59050     sda2
00000219.odp 246512517120       NO            21647     sda2
00000218.odp 246512447488       NO            21647     sda2
00000217.odp 246512422912       NO            21647     sda2
00000216.odp 246512398336       NO            21472     sda2
00000215.odp 246512373760       NO            21472     sda2
00000214.odp 246512222208       NO            22227     sda2
00000213.odp 246512197632       NO            22227     sda2
00000212.odp 246511828992       NO            26766     sda2
00000035.odt 246659334144       NO            56871     sda2
00000034.odt 246659186688       NO            56871     sda2
00000033.odt 246658629632       NO            56809     sda2
00000038.odt 247273463808       NO            51310     sda2
00000037.odt 247273123840       NO            28399     sda2
00000036.odt 247273095168       NO            28399     sda2
00000041.odt 247275417600       NO            64670     sda2
00000040.odt 247275237376       NO            41323     sda2
00000039.odt 247275192320       NO            41323     sda2
00000042.odt 256493486080       NO            71190     sda2
00000043.odt 322483257344       YES        20000000     sda2
00000044.odt 323462103040       NO           363314     sda2
00000045.odt 325778538496       NO            67994     sda2
00000053.odt 332444651520       NO            64830     sda2
00000052.odt 332444585984       NO            64830     sda2
00000051.odt 332444241920       NO            64511     sda2
00000050.odt 332444176384       NO            64511     sda2
00000049.odt 332443537408       NO            44640     sda2
00000048.odt 332443492352       NO            44640     sda2
00000047.odt 332443267072       NO            29643     sda2
00000046.odt 332443234304       NO            29643     sda2
00000220.odp 332484366336       NO            45772     sda2
00000055.odt 333043331072       NO            13661     sda2
00000054.odt 333043277824       NO            13866     sda2
00000057.odt 333158961152       NO            35778     sda2
00000056.odt 333158924288       NO            35778     sda2
00000060.odt 335705534464       NO            57135     sda2
00000059.odt 335705477120       NO            57135     sda2
00000058.odt 335705059328       NO            56871     sda2
00000221.odp 349310341120       NO            45772     sda2
00000062.odt 354530766848       NO            13661     sda2
00000061.odt 354530713600       NO            13866     sda2
00000063.odt 354655182848       NO            51457     sda2
00000065.odt 361309286400       NO            10258     sda2
00000064.odt 361309274112       NO            10258     sda2
00000222.odp 372202671259       NO              131     sda2
00000196.ods 372202671102       NO              131     sda2
00000066.odt 372202670953       NO              123     sda2
00000067.odt 374029000704       NO            43955     sda2
00000068.odt 374137524224       NO            28259     sda2
00000071.odt 374502830080       NO            56941     sda2
00000070.odt 374501724160       NO            56941     sda2
00000069.odt 374501666816       NO            56941     sda2
00000072.odt 374532067328       NO            56941     sda2
00000073.odt 377623543808       NO            76407     sda2
00000074.odt 381290549248       NO            57673     sda2
00000080.odt 381299466240       NO            48719     sda2
00000079.odt 381299417088       NO            48719     sda2
00000078.odt 381295329280       NO            57673     sda2
00000077.odt 381295267840       NO            57678     sda2
00000076.odt 381295206400       NO            57678     sda2
00000075.odt 381294149632       NO            57553     sda2
00000082.odt 381444202496       NO            59210     sda2
00000081.odt 381444141056       NO            59210     sda2
00000087.odt 381517520896       NO            51310     sda2
00000086.odt 381517467648       NO            51310     sda2
00000085.odt 381516627968       NO            59210     sda2
00000084.odt 381516201984       NO            42408     sda2
00000083.odt 381516156928       NO            42408     sda2
00000088.odt 381567524864       NO            57678     sda2
00000091.odt 381682532352       NO            51592     sda2
00000090.odt 381682438144       NO            51592     sda2
00000089.odt 381682319360       NO            47849     sda2
00000093.odt 381723653557       YES        20000000     sda2
00000092.odt 381723607138       YES        20000000     sda2
00000095.odt 382001963008       NO            32712     sda2
00000094.odt 382001913856       NO            19858     sda2
00000097.odt 382751465472       NO            61253     sda2
00000096.odt 382751404032       NO            61253     sda2
00000099.odt 382850899968       NO            29191     sda2
00000098.odt 382850867200       NO            29191     sda2
00000105.odt 382906286080       NO            57015     sda2
00000104.odt 382906150912       NO            57015     sda2
00000103.odt 382906093568       NO            57015     sda2
00000102.odt 382906028032       NO            56949     sda2
00000101.odt 382905970688       NO            56949     sda2
00000100.odt 382905847808       NO            11858     sda2
00000225.odp 384853735445       NO              131     sda2
00000224.odp 384853314443       NO              131     sda2
00000223.odp 384853304473       NO              131     sda2
00000199.ods 384853735601       NO              131     sda2
00000198.ods 384853314599       NO              131     sda2
00000197.ods 384853304629       NO              131     sda2
00000108.odt 384853735757       NO              123     sda2
00000107.odt 384853314755       NO              123     sda2
00000106.odt 384853304785       NO              123     sda2
00000109.odt 385009569792       NO            15531     sda2
00000110.odt 385024008192       NO            15531     sda2
00000228.odp 385027400495       NO              131     sda2
00000227.odp 385027375919       NO              131     sda2
00000226.odp 385027334959       NO              131     sda2
00000202.ods 385027400651       NO              131     sda2
00000201.ods 385027376075       NO              131     sda2
00000200.ods 385027335115       NO              131     sda2
00000117.odt 385036374016       NO            26925     sda2
00000116.odt 385036345344       NO            26925     sda2
00000115.odt 385036181504       NO            25976     sda2
00000114.odt 385036152832       NO            25976     sda2
00000113.odt 385027400807       NO              123     sda2
00000112.odt 385027376231       NO              123     sda2
00000111.odt 385027335271       NO              123     sda2
00000120.odt 385904201728       NO            64812     sda2
00000119.odt 385903742976       NO            55075     sda2
00000118.odt 385903685632       NO            55075     sda2
00000121.odt 386372194304       NO            64812     sda2
00000122.odt 403871420416       NO            67490     sda2
00000132.odt 404601462784       NO            57673     sda2
00000131.odt 404601217024       NO            57673     sda2
00000130.odt 404600008704       NO            57553     sda2
00000129.odt 404599341056       NO            57507     sda2
00000128.odt 404599107584       NO            56863     sda2
00000127.odt 404598841344       NO            56475     sda2
00000126.odt 404598251520       NO            55470     sda2
00000125.odt 404598013952       NO            55262     sda2
00000124.odt 404597506048       NO            54883     sda2
00000123.odt 404597243904       NO            54435     sda2
00000134.odt 406155063296       NO            48578     sda2
00000133.odt 406155014144       NO            48578     sda2
00000135.odt 423825518592       NO            23473     sda2
00000137.odt 436442365952       NO            76178     sda2
00000136.odt 436442234880       NO            76178     sda2
00000139.odt 437631172608       NO            53630     sda2
00000138.odt 437631115264       NO            53630     sda2
00000144.odt 444455059456       NO            61235     sda2
00000143.odt 444454821888       NO            60494     sda2
00000142.odt 444454592512       NO            59831     sda2
00000141.odt 444454440960       NO            59549     sda2
00000140.odt 444454223872       NO            58893     sda2
00000145.odt 457728016384       NO            13661     sda2
00000229.odp 458216093969       NO              131     sda2
00000203.ods 458216093812       NO              131     sda2
00000146.odt 458216093663       NO              123     sda2
00000147.odt 458279878656       NO            76178     sda2
00000149.odt 459706834944       NO            57548     sda2
00000148.odt 459706773504       NO            57548     sda2
00000151.odt 459865214976       NO            59050     sda2
00000150.odt 459865088000       NO            60355     sda2
00000152.odt 460304388096       NO            43955     sda2
00000153.odt 460356788224       NO            43955     sda2
00000158.odt 460393865216       NO            43955     sda2
00000157.odt 460389191680       NO            60568     sda2
00000156.odt 460389015552       NO            59879     sda2
00000155.odt 460388745216       NO            56023     sda2
00000154.odt 460388577280       NO            33454     sda2
00000159.odt 460509990912       NO            60355     sda2
00000161.odt 460847316992       NO            75503     sda2
00000160.odt 460847185920       NO            75503     sda2
00000230.odp 460892059921       NO              131     sda2
00000204.ods 460892059764       NO              131     sda2
00000162.odt 460892059615       NO              123     sda2
00000164.odt 461019455488       NO             9790     sda2
00000163.odt 461019443200       NO             9790     sda2
00000167.odt 461272621056       NO            59563     sda2
00000166.odt 461272559616       NO            59563     sda2
00000165.odt 461270708224       NO            31029     sda2
00000169.odt 461319307264       NO            67556     sda2
00000168.odt 461317472256       NO            67556     sda2
00000231.odp 461651213650       NO              131     sda2
00000205.ods 461651213493       NO              131     sda2
00000170.odt 461651213344       NO              123     sda2
00000232.odp 461693155766       NO              131     sda2
00000206.ods 461693155609       NO              131     sda2
00000171.odt 461693155460       NO              123     sda2
00000172.odt 461904150528       NO            75194     sda2
00000173.odt 462387863552       NO            60861     sda2
00000174.odt 462430027776       NO            60861     sda2
00000176.odt 462503186432       NO            51859     sda2
00000175.odt 462503133184       NO            51859     sda2
00000181.odt 462513750016       NO            60756     sda2
00000180.odt 462513688576       NO            60756     sda2
00000179.odt 462512824320       NO            60655     sda2
00000178.odt 462512664576       NO            60655     sda2
00000177.odt 462512431104       NO            60069     sda2
00000186.odt 490980745216       NO            59253     sda2
00000185.odt 490980409344       NO            57755     sda2
00000184.odt 490979966976       NO            48092     sda2
00000183.odt 490979917824       NO            48092     sda2
00000182.odt 490979581952       NO            33107     sda2
00000190.odt 495273373696       NO            60073     sda2
00000189.odt 495272992768       NO            60193     sda2
00000188.odt 495272685568       NO            59253     sda2
00000187.odt 495272243200       NO            57755     sda2
00000192.odt 495414734848       NO            60073     sda2
00000191.odt 495414460416       NO            60193     sda2


Completed at Mon Jul  4 12:59:00 2016
```

But the folder is empty having lock icon.
I don't know how to recover my files now. It's really important for me,Please Help ! I will be really grateful.

Comment: first, YOU SHOULD NEVER write in the same disk/partition from where you intend to recover files, if you "deleted them" they are still there as data, but the space is marked as usable, so any other operation can write over your file. That said, i prefer to use `photorec` (with sudo), which usually gets all the data/files, it also has filetype filters, but i dont know if it has odt as option.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your suggestion @bistoco :)

Comment: «I don't have any other partition except that. So I made a folder on Desktop.» **Terrible** idea. I'm glad that you managed to solve the problem, although you risked a lot!

Comment: Yes, I am gonna make partition. I was at fault but somehow managed solving my problem. Thanx for suggestion @AndreaLazzarotto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recovered all of my files in accurate form. The thing was that I got multiple copies of same file so I had to choose the mostly correct one. But I am happy that I found that.

What I did was:
As all operations were using super user. So I used command below:

1. `sudo su`
2. After entering the password, I changed my directory as all data were there but in root form.So I changed directory as:

   ```
   cd ~/Desktop/fhghghg/
   ```
3. As all the data were present there , so to see my odt file I listed all the files that are present:

   ```
   ~/Desktop/fhghghg# ls -la
   ```

   then I got following response:

   ```
   total 56
   drwxrwxrwx 5 root root  4096 Jul  4 12:58 .
   drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Jul  4 16:29 ..
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12713 Jul  4 12:59 audit.txt
   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jul  4 12:58 odp-2-0
   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jul  4 12:58 ods-1-0
   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 20480 Jul  4 16:52 odt-0-0
   ```
4. There I found that my recovered files are available in **odt-0-0** , so again I changed directory as:

   ```
   ~/Desktop/fhghghg# cd ~/Desktop/fhghghg/odt-0-0/
   ```
5. There I listed my all the files:

   ```
   ~/Desktop/fhghghg/odt-0-0# ls -all
   ```

   Then got following response:

   ```
   total 68624
   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    20480 Jul  4 16:52 .
   drwxrwxrwx 5 root root     4096 Jul  4 12:58 ..
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    66578 Jul  4 12:58 00000000.odt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   175449 Jul  4 12:58 00000001.odt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    72438 Jul  4 12:58 00000002.odt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    66656 Jul  4 12:58 00000003.odt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    67311 Jul  4 12:58 00000004.odt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    74935 Jul  4 12:58 00000005.odt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   356733 Jul  4 12:58 00000006.odt
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root      123 Jul  4 12:58 00000007.odt
   ..
   ..
   ```
6. So again I opened one of the files with the help of Libreoffice with :

   ```
   libreoffice 00000000.odt
   ```

   And got one of my files opened. Then I save this copy of the file by:

   ```
    LibreOffice --> File --> Save as Copy --> File Systems --> Desktop
   ```

**Note**: Don't do this LibreOffice --> File --> Save as Copy -->  Desktop

or else you will be again in trouble as this "Desktop" is on root mode and again you won't be able to see your files.

7. Then I found my first recovered file on my Desktop screen, but there was lock icon on that, so it was read only file. To change it to editable mode, I used:

   ```
   chmod 777 -R /home/(user_name)/Desktop/(file_name).odt
   ```

Some hard work was needed but finally I recovered my files.

**Note**:All commands are in root mode.